# vba function which returns more than one value and so can be called in sql

Tags: sql, vba

I'm new to VBA and i need help.
I want to create vba function which takes table name as input, and distinct specific field from that table. I created function, and it works when i run it in vba immediate window (when i use debug.print command to display results). But when i call this function in sql, instead whole field values, it returns just last one. I'm not good at vba syntax so i need help to understand. Does function can return more than one value? If can, how, and if not what else to use? Here's my code:

```
Public Function TableInfo(tabela As String)
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Dim polje1 As Field, polje2 As Field
Dim sifMat As Field, pogon As Field, tipVred As Field

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset(tabela)
Set sifMat = rec.Fields("Field1")
Set pogon = rec.Fields("Field2")
Set tipVred = rec.Fields("Field3")

For Each polje1 In rec.Fields
    For Each polje2 In rec.Fields
        TableInfo = pogon.Value
        rec.MoveNext
    Next
Next

End Function
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line probably:

```
TableInfo = pogon.Value
```

It runs inside the loop and returns the last value of the loop.

Instead of returning one value `TableInfo`, you may try to return something similar to a `Collection` or an `Array`.

Inside the loop, append values in the Collection and after the loop, return the Collection back from the function.

### Edit:

I have re-written the code shared by you:

```
Public Function TableInfo(tabela As String) as String()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rec As Recordset
    Dim polje1 As Field, polje2 As Field
    Dim sifMat As Field, pogon As Field, tipVred As Field

    Dim returnValue() As String
    Dim i as Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset(tabela)
    Set sifMat = rec.Fields("Field1")
    Set pogon = rec.Fields("Field2")
    Set tipVred = rec.Fields("Field3")

    ' I am not going to modify this but I think we can do away with two For Each loops.
    ' Just iterate over rec like
    ' For Each r In rec -> please use proper naming conventions and best practices
    ' and access each field as r("Field1") and r("Field2")
    For Each polje1 In rec.Fields
        For Each polje2 In rec.Fields
            returnValue(i) = pogon.Value
            i = i + 1
            rec.MoveNext
        Next
    Next
    TableInfo = returnValue
End Function
```

> Please note: I have not tested this code but I assume this should work for you. Also, I have assumed that you want to return `String()` array. Please change the data type if you want to return some other type.

Comment: ok, i added values into collection, but i don't know how to return  values. I tried with return statement, but it shows me some error. Could you code me how to return values back from function? Sorry if question is stupid :)

Comment: @DejanŽivković, just before `End Function` add a line `TableInfo = collectionVariable` where **collectionVariable** is the name of the variable which you are using.

Comment: i did that and it still doesn't work. It shows me error "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" when i call my function in sql. I declared my variable : Dim obj As Collection. Then i set it as : Set obj = New Collection
In for each loop i wrote : obj.Add pogon.Value

Comment: Please share your current code. You may edit the question and append the code there. It would be easy to read there.

Comment: Public Function TableInfo(tabela As String)
Dim db As Database
Dim obj As Collection
Dim rec As Recordset
Dim polje1 As Field, polje2 As Field
Dim sifMat As Field, pogon As Field, tipVred As Field
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set obj = New Collection
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset(tabela)
Set sifMat = rec.Fields("Field1")
Set pogon = rec.Fields("Field2")
Set tipVred = rec.Fields("Field3")
For Each polje1 In rec.Fields
    For Each polje2 In rec.Fields
        obj.Add pogon.Value
        rec.MoveNext
    Next
Next
TableInfo = obj
End Function

Comment: @DejanŽivković, what is the type of array that you have to return `String` or `Int`?

Comment: @DejanŽivković, I have edited my answer for String type. Please check and let me know if it works for you. I am sorry to get you confused with Collection and Array. I should have written only Array! You may check here too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164473(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Also, I think you should remove two for-each loops to one. Two are not needed there

Comment: now i have problem in sql when i call function. When i call my function just by it's name like : SELECT TableInfo(Table), it reports type mismatch, but if i call it with ' ' or " ", it displays me just name of function. I'm confused. How to call String function in sql?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the array (as posted in theghostofc's answer), you will need to do something like this:

```
Dim TableInfo() As String

For i = LBound(TableInfo) To UBound(TableInfo)
  YourValue = TableInfo(i)
  ... Process some code that uses YourValue
Next i
```

If you're not looping through your array, you're not going to get each individual value out of it.